# « Soleil levé » pour « lever du soleil »

Tags: usage, france, groupe-nominal

*La petite Fadette*, George Sand

> — Voilà qu'il fait jour, mon Landry; dégageons-nous si nous voulons arriver avant le soleil levé.

Les constructions de ce type, où une preposition est utilisé avant une proposition participiale, n'existent pas en français.

- <s>avant le gâteau mangé, avant la pluie tombée, etc.</s>

Il doit être conclu que « soleil levé » est traité comme un groupe substantif, et donc que c'est un terme synonyme de « lever du soleil ». Peut-on toujours l'utiliser en français moderne ou bien est-ce bien un terme désuet ?

On ne le trouve pas dans le [TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soleil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est désuet ou familier - je dirais plutôt le second dans ce dialogue («mon Landry» évoque un langage parlé relâché) :

> 1 . *Arch*. ou *fam*. Avant + subst. + part. passé.
>
> a) Subst. actualisé :
>
> 30. Une petite lumière rouge s'allume sur la chaire cinq minutes avant l'heure achevée. A. Siegfried, Savoir parler en public,p. 187 (Grev.
>     1964, § 779, p. 708)
>
> b) Syntagme figé :
>
> 31. Et surtout ne t'en reviens pas vers elle avant vêpres tombées. Aragon, Le Roman inachevé,1956, p. 108.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avant